# Jenkins job execution issue

Tags: unix, jenkins, amazon-ec2, ansible

I am trying to trigger a Jenkins job which is throwing below error.Jenkins is hosted on AWS ec2 instances

```
/tmp/jenkins7326195626020563202.sh: line 4: cd: /home/ec2-user: Permission denied

Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure

Finished: FAILURE
```

My Jenkins job has below shell command to execute:

```
export ANSIBLE_FORCE_COLOR=true

cd /home/ec2-user

ansible-playbook -i hosts /home/ec2-user/installapache.yml -vvvv
```

Please help here in what I need to fix for above error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That issue happened when jenkins user doesnot have permission in /home/ec2-user.

So solution for this :

`chmod -R 777 /home/ec2-user`

OR add jenkins user to ec2-user group

OR grant jenkins user has a root permission.

Comment: Now I getting below error although  I have installed Ansible plugin and configure in Jenkins.  /tmp/jenkins3254324334919499300.sh: line 4: ansible-playbook: command not found

Comment: please create another question if you got stuck

Comment: install `ansible-playbook` in Jenkins Server